# SonarQube analysis of Stash pull requests

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have to create a Sonar dashboard view for each Stash pull request jenkins build. Is it possible to achieve it at run time? In other words I would like to create a sonar dashboard for each jenkins build.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're doing a full analysis of each pull request? I.E. you're creating a project instance in SonarQube for each pull request?

Comment: Yes this is what I want to achieve. But I think to create the project instance in SonarQube is not a good way and also you need the admin right for that. So I use the -Dsonar.branch property to use the ${sourceBranch} from the PR request. But now I am not able to attach the quality profile to the PR sonar analysis at run time. Earlier we had the property -Dsonar.profile but it is not deprecated. Is there any way to pass the sonar profile as a property?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [sonar-stash](https://github.com/AmadeusITGroup/sonar-stash) plugin for PR analysis. It won't give you a "dashboard", but will show you new issues on the changed code.